# two memory leaks with UIImagePickerController and UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

a noob question here.

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture 
{  
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) 
 { 
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  imagePicker.delegate = self;
  imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

  UIPopoverController *popVC = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: imagePicker];
  popVC.delegate = self; 
  [popVC setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 100)];
  [popVC presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(39, 356, 320, 100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:1 animated:NO];
 }
 else 
 {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error accessing photo library"
              message:@"Device does not support a photo library" delegate:nil
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
  [alert show]; 
  [alert release];
 }
}
```

but the compiler warns me about two potential memory leaks. one for imagePicker and the other for popVC. could someone please explain what needs to be changed and why. I'd really like to understand why this is happening, so I can avoid it in the future.

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not releasing `imagePicker` or `popVC` anywhere, thats why your leaking. You can add an autorelease or release somewhere in there for those.

Choose one of these methods:

```
/*  this is the method I would suggest  */
UIPopoverController *popVC = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: imagePicker] autorelease];  

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
/*  with these, you could potentially over-release somewhere, so be careful  */

[popVC release];

[imagePicker release];
```

Also, notice how you've used `[alert release];`. Same concept.

Comment: thank you! I get it now. I added auto release to imagePicker and alert, but had code a manual release in a method for popVC (because it was auto releasing while still up and crashing the app)